# How to link single-threaded CRT libc.lib?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have an application which uses an old .lib file which in-turns depend on single-threaded libc.lib.

[As I read on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh.aspx), Single-Threaded libc.lib is no longer supported and I should use Multi-threaded ones. How do I force that .lib to use multi-threaded version of libc.lib or how do I get libc.lib (single-threaded one) on visual studio 2012 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the lib owner and ask for a rebuild. If you cannot get a new release, build a DLL wrapper for the lib in a pre-VS2005 version of Visual Studio then use the DLL in your VS2012 project.

Comment: In VS2012, can we Ignore all default libs and explicitly link libc.lib ?

Comment: That CRT mixing scenario is not tested by Microsoft. If you only have one thread, it may work, but I suggest you to not risk a runtime crash if you have multiple threads.